# Using new value in AQL update

Tags: arangodb, upsert

I'm using `UPSERT`:

```
FOR doc IN temp_collection
UPSERT { _key: doc._key } 
INSERT 
{...} 
UPDATE 
{ 
    seen: OLD.seen + doc.seen
    x: (OLD.seen + doc.seen) > 10 ? 0 : 1
} 
IN main_collection
```

I'd like to replace `(OLD.seen + doc.seen)` in `x` by value from new, yet not commited `seen`. But I can't use pseudo variable `NEW` here and can use `LET` inside `UPDATE`. What else I can do if I want to get rid of the duplication?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AQL does currently not support anything to avoid this "duplication".

You may [request this as feature](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/new) but it may not easily be possible because of language restrictions that exist in order to allow certain optimizations.